# Inject Vue component with computed properties into another component programmatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs2

I'm building a list of things which have a counter associated to them, like in the following image:
[image]

I'm struggling on how I can inject the right part of each row, which is in a separate component and handles what happens when you click each button, updating its counter, whenever I click 'Add new'.

How can I inject a component, along with its dependencies and computed properties?

Comment: The vue way is to declare child components in the parent template.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem. Whenever I click 'add new' I'm picking information from an array, adding it to a new row on the table AND a new instance of my Counter.vue component should be dynamically added on that new row, already bound so that when I click + or - it updates the counter of the row itself.

Comment: Right. You can declare all of that with a `v-for`. You'll have a `row` component and a `counter` component within the `row`. The `counter` can emit increment/decrement events to the `row`.

Comment: Try a second vue that's used as an event dispatcher / listener as detailed here: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/ it could be just what you're looking for.

Comment: The second vue instance can do things like 'emit' and 'on' - so when component a eventBus.emit('somethingAwesome', {'with':data}) a different component can eventBus.on('somethingAwesome',function(e){this.$set(this,'someVar',e)});

Comment: Silly me. @EricGuan was right. My custom component relies on whatever I'm serving within the v-for, so whenever that array changes, the component will follow. I'll update the post with this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer Eric Guan gave me was right. I was complicating something that Vue solves on its own.

My custom component relies on whatever I'm serving within the v-for, so whenever that array changes, the component I have on that row will follow:

```
    <ul class="extras">
        <li v-for="extra in extras">
            <div>{{ extra.name }} </div>
            <div>{{ extra.price }}</div>

            <calculator :object="extra"></calculator>
        </li>
    </ul>
```